# cakephp and form css

Tags: css, forms, cakephp

Hi all I'm trying to create a mobile site for a website I've already created and am using in file css.

1. i am trying to make the input boxes 10% of the screen height. how can I do this?
2. how can I make the login button taller?

here is the code from the view file

```
<?php echo $this->Html->docType('xhtml-trans'); ?>
<html>


<head>
<style>
body {
background-color:#ADD8E6;
height: 960px;
width:  640px;
}

table, td, th
{   
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
}
input
{
    height:233%;
    width:70%;  
}
</style>
    <title> <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?></title>
    <?php echo $this->Html->css($stylesheet_used); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "headertwo" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/BannerGradient2.jpg);">
<center>    
<?php echo $this->Html->image($image_used, array(
    "alt" => "eBox",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'))) ?>
</center>
    </div>  
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')));?>
<table border=0 style="width:640px;">
    <tr>
    <td >Username:
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label'=>false,));?></td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>    
        <td>Password: <?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>false,));?></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Login', array('width'=>100));?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user1393064,

You're using XHTML Doctype rightnow which is not good practice now a days to achieve good result in Targeted Mobile Device.

Instead I recommend you to try HTML5 Doctype, like below...

> <!DOCTYPE html>

Additionally for Mobile support you need to add Viewport Meta

> <meta name ="viewport" content ="initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no">

Then you define your CSS for INPUT

> input { /* put your code here */ }
>
> input#submit { /* put your style here */ }

I also suggest you to use CSS Media Query for your targeted Mobile Device & Screen.

> @media screen and (max-width: 640px){
>
> body{ /* put your style here */ }
>
> form{ /* put your style here */ }
>
> input{ /* put your style here */ }
>
> input#submit{ /* put your style here */ }
>
> }

For further help you can refer to this article http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/tips-tricks-how-to-optimize-a-website-for-mobile-devices/

Comment: @user1393064,

Can you be specific which Device & Screen you're targeting?

Also you didn't mentioned why Viewport implementation affected your UI. Must be some CSS tweak is required after implementing Viewport.

And don't forgot specific Media query works for specific device only, so you must have to add Media queries for universal screens and all possible targeted screen separately.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
input
{
    font-size:200%;
    width:70%;  
}
```

did not think about including the font-size in the input as I didn't think of it as text, duhhh